# Are Fitting ideals of a finite flat module flat?

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a commutative unital ring. Let $M$ be a finite flat $A$-module. We can present $M$ as the cokernel
$$A^{\oplus J}\xrightarrow{\varphi} A^n\to M\to0$$
and there exists $a_{ij}$ for $1\leq i\leq n$ and $j\in J$ such that $\varphi(e_j)=\sum_{i=1}^na_{ij}e_i$. Consider the ideal generated by minors of $(a_{ij})$
$$\operatorname{Fit}_r(M)=\langle (n-r)\times(n-r)\textrm{-minors of }(a_{ij})\rangle. $$

Are $\operatorname{Fit}_r(M)$ flat over $A$?

Comment: Yes - they are even locally $(0)$ or $(1)$ at any prime. See Vasconcelos, [On finitely generated flat modules](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1969-138-00/S0002-9947-1969-0238839-5/S0002-9947-1969-0238839-5.pdf) (although he deals with invariant factors, these are the same as Fitting ideals up to radical)